# Mysql error while inserting a paragraph

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a Paragraph **(which contains a single quote in middle)** into database as below.

```
$rule="**Mobile's** are not allowed into the room...................soon";


mysql_query("insert into table_name (rule) values('$rule')");
```

While executing the query that paragraph is not inserting. And i have directly tried in the Mysql using SQL option. There it shown error.

Any suggestions..?

Thanks

Comment: that "error" may be interesting to read, don't you think? also, with that, which i already know, you can easily debug your problem

Comment: i suggest you to tell us the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
$rule = mysql_real_escape_string("**Mobile's** are not allowed into the room...................soon");
```

Answer (score 1):

Some questions to make you think:

1. What do double quotes (`"`) mean in PHP?
2. What are their effect on a string which contains a variable?
3. What is "input sanitation"?
4. What is "character escaping"?
5. What is PDO?

Also, and most importantly:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle such thing is to use `PDO` extension or `MySQLi`. They are designed to prevent from `SQL Injection`.

example of using `PDO`.

```
$rule = "**Mobile's** are not allowed into the room...................soon";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into table_name (rule) values(:rule)");
$stmt->execute(array(':rule' => $rule));
```

best link that I can give that explains how bad is the query the breaks when a value contains single quotes:

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You may use mysql_real_escape_string() before sending values to Mysql database table.
please check this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

```
$rule="**Mobile's** are not allowed into the room...................soon";
$rule1=mysql_real_escape_string($rule)
mysql_query("insert into table_name (rule) values('$rule1')");
```